# Cant connect to localhost

Tags: visualstudio

I have a project um Visual Studio with a GET method:
http://localhost:4548/Arduino/request?id=12&user=username&pass=password
When I open it in my browser, it works fine
But I want http GET in my Arduino, using the WebClient exemple:

**EDIT**
I used solution number 1. of @Matt and it worked:
Get a full licensed copy of IIS.
And this is the code after all:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

//Informacoes de endereco IP, gateway, mascara de rede
byte mac[] = { 0xA4, 0x28, 0x72, 0xCA, 0x55, 0x2F };
byte ip[] = { 192, 168, 1, 200 };
byte gateway[] = { 192, 168, 1, 1 };
byte subnet[] = { 255, 255, 255, 0 };
byte server[] = { 192, 168, 1, 100 };

EthernetClient client;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  // start the Ethernet connection:
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
    // try to congifure using IP address instead of DHCP:
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  }
  // give the Ethernet shield a second to initialize:
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("connecting...");

  // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println("connected");
    // Make a HTTP request:
    client.println("GET /myProject/request?id=12&user=username&pass=password HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: 192.168.1.100");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
  } else {
    // if you didn't get a connection to the server:
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
}

void loop() {
  // if there are incoming bytes available
  // from the server, read them and print them:
  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }

  // if the server's disconnected, stop the client:
  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("disconnecting.");
    client.stop();

    // do nothing forevermore:
    while (true);
  }
}
```

My Serial displays as connected, but the http GET does not work
Am I missing something?

Comment: You understand that "localhost" is *literally* the machine that the code is running on, right?

Comment: Yes. I tryed 192.168.1.100 instead of localhost but didnt work.

Comment: I believe the Visual Studio built in web server (when you 'Run' your app/site) *only* listens on `localhost`. So even substituting the IP address is not going to work. You might need to 'publish' your web service/site before it will work.

Comment: @Thiago in the stack exchange system, questions are marked resolved not by editing the question, but by accepting an answer. Could you please put the corrected code as an answer to this question and maybe it will help someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio's web server is restricted to only servicing clients on the machine it is running on.
To do what you want to do there are a number of things you can do.

1. Get a full licensed copy of IIS. (Please stop laughing)
2. Get a version of Apache (might affect your server code and will take a while to setup)
3. Write yourself a 'proxy server'.  I think if you write a program to run on you PC that creates a socket that listens to port 8080 and forwards any messages on to the VS Web Server (use `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\10.0\WebDev.WebServer40.EXE" /port:6666 /path:C:\WebServer\Root` to start it on a fixed port) and forward any replies back to you client.

Comment: 1. Get a full licensed copy of IIS. -> It worked, Thanks!!!